# R sweave plotting PNG

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am trying to put .png files into a pdf using this code:

```
<<, echo = FALSE, dev = "png", dpi = 300,  warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'asis', fig.cap = "">>=
    setwd(data.dir)
    files.all <- dir()
    for (fn in files.all){
      if (grepl("Raw_Data*",fn)){
        im <- load.image(fn)
        print(plot(im,axes=FALSE,xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n")) 
        cat("\n\\clearpage\n")
      }
    }
```

Latex produces the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cimg_library::CImgIOException'
  what():  cimg::stderr(): Reference to 'stderr' stream not allowed in R mode ('cimg_use_r' is defined).
```

Any suggestions on what the problem is?

Comment: You need to make the example reproducible.  It doesn't need to be the original document, but it does need to be something we can run to try out.  Without that, we can just guess:  the error is coming from the `imager` package, which is probably trying to signal some error.  Maybe the image was not readable?